# How to check if string | number is in array that could be in different types?

Tags: typescript

I have a variable that can be `string | number` and I have a variable that can be `string | number | string[] | number[]`. When I'm trying to check if, let's say, string is in array of strings, I'm having this error:

> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string & number'.
>     Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.

How to fix this? Here's my code example:

```
var value : string | number = '1'

var testArr : string | number | string[] | number[] = ['1']

if(!(testArr as string[] | number[]).includes(value)) {
  testAr.push(value)
}
```

Comment: If `testArr` is an array, is it really going to be `string[] | number[]` and not `(string | number)[]`?  Even if the answer is yes you might be able to get away with `(testArr as Array<string | number>).includes(value)`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing here is in casting done inside the condition. You are saying that the type is `number[] | string[]`. But `includes` method can work or with one or with another, as for `number` it requires `number`, for `string` it requires `string`.

To have it working you need to cast it more directly into `string[]`. Then it will just work.